# Disk renaming udev rule

Tags: udev, raid-controller, ide

I have two separate controllers, SATA and PATA.
I would like to rename drives connected to the PATA to hd[a-z], and their partitions to hd[a-z][0-9].

```
# udevadm info -a -p /sys/block/sdd
[...]
 looking at device '[...]/target8:0:1/8:0:1:0/block/sdd':
    KERNEL=="sdd"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
[...]
looking at parent device '[...]/target8:0:1': 
    KERNELS=="target8:0:1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
[...]
 looking at parent device '[...]':
    KERNELS=="0000:02:00.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="pata_jmicron"
```

Knowing that i tried to write new rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/59-drives.rules:

```
DRIVERS=="pata_jmicron", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNELS=="target8:0:0", NAME="hda"
DRIVERS=="pata_jmicron", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNELS=="target8:0:1", NAME="hdb"
```

No luck though. What am I missing?

PS. Persistent block device naming? No, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out kernel devices cannot be renamed:

```
udevd[648]: NAME="hdb" ignored, kernel device nodes can not be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/59-drives.rules:2
```

Comment: Please make this a real answer with an explanation.